# prompting a user to press a certain key in c

Tags: c, microcontroller, 68hc12

I am using icc12 (ImageCraft) and a hc6812 microcontroller.  I want to prompt the user to press the zero key on the LCD keypad for the next menu to appear on the LCD display.  I can't seem to get my code to do this.  ( zero key pressed = 0b11110000)

```
  if ((PTH & 0x1f) != 0x10) // if zero key pressed...
  {

  lcd_init();  // initialise the lcd module
  lcd_clear(); // clear the lcd module

  lcd_putstr(" *New menu is displayed* ");
  }
```

The keypad makes use of the upper 5 bits of Port H, it has 16 keys (0-f) and the most upper bit is high when the key that is pressed is odd and it is low when the key pressed is high. 
Port H is an input port which is connected to the keypad on my LCD module.
I'm trying to make use of a mask to show when the zero key is pressed but when I run the program the LCD module display goes straight to the new menu.  Is masking the best way to do this and if so how can I change my IF statement for the code to function properly?

Comment: You are checking other port values too, suggest `if ((PTH & 0x1f) == 0x0f)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I just tried this and although it doesn't skip straight to the new menu it has no response when zero is pressed @WeatherVane

Comment: You just changed the question, but you do not say how many (which) port bits are from the keyboard.

Comment: sorry I posted the zero key bits incorrectly.  So the keypad only uses the upper 5 bits, the keypad has 0 - F on it. @WeatherVane

Comment: See [ask]  and provide a [mcve]. Not idea why you even mention port `B`.

Comment: If the zero key is found at pin 4 and is active low, you should write `if( (PTH & (1<<4)) == 0)`. That being said, there is not enough info to answer the question. Did you set up DDRH? How do you debounce the key? Which 68HC12 is this and does it have a port routing register (MODRR) that applies to this port? Are any other hardware peripheral on that port (SPI, PWM, timers etc) active? Are you using pull resistors, if so are they internal or external?

Comment: yes DDRH is set up. its a Motorola 68HC12 16 bit microcontroller. it has an SPI port that my LCD module screen connects to.  I am unsure about the rest. @Lundin

Comment: @user_1 It matters _which_ 68HC12 this is. For example HCS12DP256 or whatever.  Namely if there are any peripherals present and potentially active on those pins. Because as soon as you activate a peripheral that is shared with GPIO, the peripheral takes precedence and the GPIO is disconnected from the pins. So if you enable SPI on that port, it is going to disable 4 GPIO pins for you: MOSI, MISO, SS and SCLK. You can no longer use those pins for GPIO while SPI is enabled. And if there is a module routing register, you must check how it is configured.

Comment: If you don't know about pull resistors nor about signal de-bouncing, you cannot possibly succeed in writing a program which reads a keyboard. You'll have to study these things... it's usually found in any beginner-level material on embedded systems programming. Pretty much any button out there will need both pull resistors and de-bouncing to work. You can use internal or external pull resistors. You can use software de-bouncing or a hardware RC filter.